# "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" error when I try to insert date to Access database by C#

Tags: c#, datetime, insert

I want to insert a date record to an Access database. Here is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AlarmHistory(Date) VALUES ('6/8/2012')"; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It gives `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.` error at second row.

The screenshot that show my cell data type on db is below.

[image: Cell data type at db]

Comment: I have searched a lot and tried many things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353541/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-while-using-datetime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522924/insert-datetime-parameter-in-access-with-oledb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449284/problem-with-inserting-date-to-ms-access-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527958/trouble-inserting-datetime-into-access-with-oledb I don't know why this process is so hard!

Comment: Try wrapping square brackets around Date - it's a keyword! So your statement would be INSERT INTO AlarmHistory ([Date]) VALUES (#6/8/2012#)

Comment: Finally it worked! Thanks @dash. So the problem was at column name (Date), not value

Comment: Yes! The database engine could be a lot better at telling people this. It leads to all sorts of confusion. I would also take @Steve advice as well though. Parameterising your queries is good practice, and boosts performance in many database systems.

Comment: @dash, good catch, You got it a few minutes before

Comment: Guys, how about the time? It doesn't work: "INSERT INTO AlarmHistory([Time]) VALUES ('17:55')". I am using ShortTime type in Access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parameters

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AlarmHistory([Date]) VALUES (?)";  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", new DateTime(2012,06,8));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will preserve your code from [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you could stop to worry about quoting your values-

Just tried creating a dummy database. It's the Date Field. You should enclose in square brackets because `Date` is a reserved keyword

[Here the list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266/en-us) of the reserved keywords for Jet 4.0

Comment: That looks good but It gave the same error. Are my Access settings OK?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `date` is a reserved word.  If so, it should be delimited (maybe with brackets):

```
INSERT INTO AlarmHistory([Date]) VALUES ('6/8/2012')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use

`"INSERT INTO AlarmHistory(Date) VALUES ('#6/8/2012#')"`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a # sign around the date that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

please remember before creating database table avoid to give fields names DATE and NAME

it will throws error while inserting. eg..give field password ,date instead of give like that ,password_user ,bill_date

**Note:date and password not acceptable field name in MS Access table .bcoz it is a keywords.**

**IT SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM**

Thanks.
Rathina.